# Is it possible to add a description to a user defined type?

Tags: postgresql, enums

When using the PostgreSQL cli I can run `\dT` and see a list of my defined ENUMs

```
postgres=# \dT
         List of data types    
 Schema |         Name         | Description
--------+----------------------+-------------
 public | collection_qualifier |
 public | image_class          |
 public | profile_type         |    
(3 rows)
```

There is a `Description` column, but I do not see any way to add a comment to type.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`comment on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html)

```
comment on type profile_type is 'The type for profiles'
```